# Как достать значение из application.yml

Tags: kotlin, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Есть файл `application.yml` . В нем хранятся данные в формате YAML:

```
settings:
  accessToken: 5e43a188-da723f-45b4-b78d-d3ede5f78ccf,
  confidenceThreshold: 0.2,
  fillingSettings: FillingSettings.DEFAULT,
  classifierNBest: 5,
  Url: "https://app.exemple.com/pub/api/app/p"
```

Как достать значение из, допустим, `settings.Url` в переменную?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько путей:

1. Через поле

   ```
    @Value("${settings.Url}")
    private String url;
   ```
2. Через Класс параметров

   ```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "settings")
    public class SettingsProperties {
        private String accessToken;
        private Double confidenceThreshold;
        private FillingSettings fillingSettings;
        private Integer classifierNBest;
        private URL Url;
    }
   ```

В котлине должно быть примерно тоже самое.

Comment: Однако, когда я пытаюсь идти по первому или  второму варианту, в переменных хранится null. А не значение из YAML. В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: уберите запятые в yml. Я только что проверил - всё работает)

Comment: Убрал. Не помогло, println(url) - возвращает null. Что я могу делать не так?)

Comment: @Daniil1703 может закинете код куда-нибудь в github? Возможно application.yml отсутствует в ресурсах по каким-то причинам